# Django : Ajax Post error : POST //[object%20Object] HTTP/1.1" 405 0

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django, post

I am trying with ajax login method. I am getting an error "POST //[object%20Object] HTTP/1.1" 405 0". I dnt know where i made the mistake.

views.py

```
class LoginVerify(View):
    print('login')
    def post(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        print("post called")
        return HttpResponse("verified")
```

html

```
<script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
          $("#loginform").on("submit", function(){
             $.post({
                 data: {csrfmiddlewaretoken:'{{ csrf_token }}'},
             url: "{% url 'feeds:login_view' %}",
             success: function(data){
                  alert(data);
              },
    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
        alert('login failed - please try again');
    }
});
          });
      });
    </script>

  <body> 
  <form id ="login_form" method="post"> 
{% csrf_token %} 
<input type="text" id="username">
<input type ="password" id="password" />
<input type="submit" value="login" />
</form>
```

urls.py

```
   urlpatterns = patterns('',
                           url(r'^hello/',views.FeedContents.as_view(),name='main'),
                           url(r'^$',views.LoginVerify.as_view(),name="login_view"),
                      )
```

pls save my day .. Thanks in advance

Result : 
Blank page is showing in the browser .. 
And in the terminal it is showing "[12/Apr/2015 15:41:51] "POST /hello/ HTTP/1.1" 405 0"

Comment: Could you edit and add the result code for the jQuery script after template rendering?

Answer (score 0):

You only post `csrf_token` to server, you should use `FormData` to serialize your form data and send that to your server.

`var fd = new FormData($("#loginform")[0]);
$.post({
    data: fd,
    url: "{% url 'feeds:login_view' %}",
    // and other stuff
})`